# C requires that a struct or union has at least one member - but members *have* been defined

Tags: c, struct, member, defined

I have a problem with my struct definition.
I define it here:

```
#ifndef CHALLENGE_SYSTEM_H_
#define CHALLENGE_SYSTEM_H_

#include "visitor_room.h"

typedef struct SChallengeRoomSystem
{

#include "challenge_room_system_fields.h";

} ChallengeRoomSystem;

#endif
```

And the file "challenge_room_system_fields.h" is:

```
#ifndef CHALLENGE_ROOM_SYSTEM_FIELDS_H_
#define CHALLENGE_ROOM_SYSTEM_FIELDS_H_
#include "visitor_room.h"

struct VisitorList {
    Visitor* visitor;
    struct VisitorList* next;
};
struct VisitorList* list;
char *name;
int num_of_challenges;
Challenge* challenges;
int num_of_rooms;
ChallengeRoom* rooms;
int last_time;

#endif
```

The following code gives me the error: "error C2016 C requires that a struct or union has at least one member". I don't understand why it doesn't work because I did declare members in the struct.
P.S. It's part of my homework and I have to define the members of the struct in the "challenge_room_system_fields.h" file. Also, "visitor_room.h" is another file in this project but it's not the reason of the problem for sure.

Comment: Remove the include guard (`define`/`ifndef`) and see if it works. If you included this header more than once, the second time it will be empty. Also note that, at least in the code you posted, it looks like including that header inside the `struct` will cause syntax errors

Comment: I'm suspicious that whatever is in `visitor_room.h` is interfering where it is included by `challenge_room_system_fields.h`.  I cannot be certain, however, unless you actually present that.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 complains about the semicolon at the end of `#include "challenge_room_system_fields.h";`, so you might try removing that. That said, I would fire anyone who wrote code like this.

Comment: You have a good point, @slezica, and I'm inclined to agree that if `challenge_room_system_fields.h` is intended only to provide the contents of `struct SChallengeRoomSystem` then it does not need and should not have include guards.  I'm not convinced that that explains the OP's problem, however.

Comment: The mutual inclusion is a bad idea here.

Comment: The error message suggests that you are compiling this as a C program (as does the use of `typedef`). This is certainly one of the cases where C and C++ are different: The nested `struct` definition is treated differently by the two languages. I don't think that fact is relevant to your question, so I just removed the tag [tag:c++]

Comment: Try running the preprocessor on those files and see what code you end up with. May be it will shed some light.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @slezica it doesn't work, it just creates more errors like "error C2059: syntax error : '}' " and " struct type redefiniton - and the original error still reamins

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have to do the mutual inclusion

Comment: It's been a while since I used C, so maybe I'm thinking wrong, but maybe the compiler is attempting to redefine VisitorList at the struct VisitorList* line, thus causing the error. In other words, is the struct keyword being used correctly?

Comment: @RexGray I'm pretty sure it is, but thanks anyway for the help